# How to stream images as video with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, video-streaming

I'm generating images in a nodejs app (I have them in memory as Buffer objects).

I create them (a couple of images per second) and when the image is created I send it to the client via WebSockets. In the browser I render the image with the IMG tag

This works, although not very fast. So to improve the performance I was wondering if there  is a way using Nodejs to convert these images into a video stream (I guess this is more efficient) so I can simply use the VIDEO element in the browser? Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Comment: Maybe I dont understand that but does [it](https://shotstack.io/learn/turn-images-into-slideshow-video-nodejs/) work for you ?

Comment: It seems that you have to send the images to some external party and it is not free. This will probably be to slow